# USB to Serial Converter not working Perfectly

Tags: c#

I have downloaded the driver files from Atmel corporations website. The downloaded file is atm6124_cdc.inf. Its a USB to serial port Converter. It was installed by going to device mangager window, then coming to Ports. Here it was shown in yellow color which means it was not detected by windows. by right clickinng on it we could see the 'Update device driver'. I followed the installation steps and finally driver was got installed. After that I start my application, the driver communicated with the hardware and again changed to unidentified state.

I have a USB device as hardware but it won't be immediately visible in Windows explorer. We have to send a string via serial port communication for unlocking.
After unlocking only the device is detected in windows explorer. Here what I am facing with the driver is, it actually unlocks my device and shown in Windows explorer and immediately after that the driver switches to unidentified state.

I am using Windows 8.1 operating system. Is there any way to sustain the driver behaviour even after unlocking the device.

Comment: I had a similar problem with a SeaLink USB-RS232 converter that worked with Win7 and 8, but not 8.1.  I contacted the manufacturer and they provided an updated release that fixed the problem.  I know this is not the same device as yours, but there does seem to have been some significant change for these types of devices at 8.1.

Comment: Check USB settings for 8 bit, No Parity, No Handshaking (hardware,software),1 stop Usually issues like this hardware handshaking is enable,or the cable has the hardware wires connected and interfering with the driver.Turing off hardware controls can solve issue or replace cable (one with only pins 2 and 3) may help.Also I've seen some of these devices have the PC +5V connected on one of the pins which sometimes create issues.A USB connector has 5V on a pin and some device put it on one of the 9 pin connectors.Then if the 9 pin connector/cable has the wire connected it shorts the PC supply.

Comment: I will explain the settings. Baud rate is 115200, No parity, 8 bit, Stopbit is 1 and No HandShake